How do you make sure an alias is always pointing to the latest version of a Lambda function using CDK?
I have a Lambda with an alias, but the Lambda code changes frequently, and I'm trying to figure out a way to have the Lambda version up to date and keep the alias pointing to the latest version, (without messing with things in the console, I want to keep everything in the CDK).
The Lambda:
lambda_fn = _lambda.Function(
            self,
            "MainLambda",
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_12,
            handler="main.handler",
            memory_size=1024,
            vpc=vpc,
            security_groups=[sg_vidual_lambda],
            vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(
                subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED
            ),
            environment=env_vars,
            timeout=Duration.seconds(30),
            role=multi_service_role,
            code=_lambda.Code.from_bucket(
                bucket=packages_bucket, key="deployment_package.zip"
            ),
        )

The alias:
lambda_alias = _lambda.Alias(
            self,
            "MainLambdaAlias",
            alias_name="DEV",
            version=lambda_fn.current_version,
            provisioned_concurrent_executions=1,
        )

Is there a convenient way of publishing

You would need to move your lambda code to the CDK repo, so that each change to the code triggers a CDK deployment that would create a new version.
